# How can I send MyObject through an ObjectOutputStream Client/Server Java?

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, objectoutputstream

I'm making a client/server java application with sockets and i'm trying to send MyObject which implements Serializable, but the client receives only 'null';
It already works perfectly with primitive types.
Here's the **Server Code**.

```
ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

MyObject a = new MyObject( MyObjA b, MyObjB c);

output.writeObject(a);
```

**Client Code**

```
ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
MyObject a = (MyObject) input.readObject();
```

**MyObject Class**

```
public class MyObject implements Serializable
{
    private MyObj a;
    private MyObj b;

    public MyObject(MyObj a, MyObj b)
    {
       this.a = a;
       this.b = b; 
    }
 }
```

Both Classes MyObjA and MyObjB implements Serializable

**Solved!**
I didn't serialized correctly MyObjB

Comment: Be sure to call output.flush() method.

Comment: after .writeObject() ?

Comment: adding output.flush() after each writing, no changes..

Comment: Are `MyObjA b, MyObjB c` initialized?

Comment: Yes 
b = new MyObjA(String name);
c = new MyObjB(String name);

Comment: `MyObj <> MyObjA` and `MyObj<>MyObjB` how does your constructor work? Post complete code if possible!